# Parsing URL error

Tags: java, android, java-io

It didn't seem like there was a post about this, so here goes. I've been working on a simple app to grab my time table from my school, and get it on my phone. Currently I'm working on the port on android but I've hit an issue. I get the error:

> java.io.IOException: -1 error loading URL urladress.

Code:

```
public void updateTimeTable(){
    //Get UID and Birthday
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String uid = prefs.getString("uid", "000000");
    String fods = prefs.getString("fodsdag", "000000");

    //Set URL
    String url = "http://unv1.aalborg-stu.dk/cgi-bin/elevskema.pl?ugen=0&unavn=" + uid + "&fodsdag=" + fods;


    try { 
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements td = doc.getElementsByTag("td");
    //ArrayList<String> tdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
   //  for (Element tds : td) {
    //    String tdText = tds.text();
    //    tdArray.add(tdText);
     //}
 //String[] data = tdArray.toArray(new String[tdArray.size()]);   


    } catch (IOException e ){

     Log.e("Parser", "shite", e);

    }
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = url;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

I've commented some lines out to identify where the issue is, and it seems it's at the actual parsing. Anywho, screenshot of the error I get:

[Screenshot](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/2061/errorwy.jpg)

I got about 4 days worth of Java experience so forgive me if it's something silly.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. hard to say like that, but in a lucky guess, did you set the internet permission in the manifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yeah I had the issue with internet permission earlier - that produced another error, which by setting the permission, was fixed.